# Descendant From vs Of

Tags: prepositions

Consider the following sentences and explain which one I should use:

> "Frederick was a descendant **of** a line of Firefighters."
>
> "Frederick was a descendant **from** a line of Firefighters."

If you can, explain the reasons for your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone is **a descendant of**...

Someone is **descended from**...

See [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/descendant): A descendant is one **descended from** another.  Usage example: Many people in this area are **descendants of** German immigrants.